# Opposite of factorize function (Map numeric to categorical values)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, categorical-data

I am searching for a way to map some numeric columns to categorical features.

All columns are of categorical nature but are represented as integers. However I need them to be a "String".

e.g.

```
col1 col2 col3 ->  col1new col2new col3new
0     1    1   ->  "0"     "1"     "1"
2     2    3   ->  "2"     "2"     "3"
1     3    2   ->  "1"     "3"     "2"
```

It does not matter what kind of String the new column contains as long as all distinct values from the original data set map to the same new String value.

Any ideas?

I have a bumpy representation of my data right now but any pandas solution would be also helpful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just FYI: ints are as good categorical features representation as a string. ML models should have an option to provide information which features you want to treat as categorical and which as ordinal. What are you using that requires string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `applymap` method. Cosider the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 2, 1], 'col2': [1, 2, 3], 'col3': [1, 3, 2]})
df.applymap(str)

     col1 col2 col3
0    0    1    1
1    2    2    3
2    1    3    2
```

You can convert all elements of `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` to `str` using the following command:

```
df = df.applymap(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the type of the elements in a list by using the `dataframe.apply` function which is offered by [pandas-dataframe-apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply).

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 90, size =(5000000, 3)), columns =['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

in the new dataframe you can define columns and the value by:

```
updated_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 90, size =(5000000, 3)), columns =['col1new', 'col2new', 'col3new'])
updated_frame['col1new'] = frame['col1'].apply(str)
updated_frame['col2new'] = frame['col2'].apply(str)
updated_frame['col3new'] = frame['col3'].apply(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) method. If you want to replace all the current columns with a string version then you could do (`df` your dataframe):

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

If you want to add the string columns as new ones:

```
df = df.assign(**{f"{col}new": df[col].astype(str) for col in df.columns})
```